# Are c++11 signals equivalent to boost.signals

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, signals

As I undersand many boost libs are included in c++11 standart. After changing `boost::` to `std::` I have managed to compile them using c++11 compiler. I have problem to compile this code which contains `boost::signals`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>
#include <csignal>

void func()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{ 
    std::signal<void()> s;
    s.connect(func);
    s();      
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:12:19: error: invalid operands of types ‘void (*(int, __sighandler_t)throw ())(int) {aka void (*(int, void (*)(int))throw ())(int)}’ and ‘void’ to binary ‘operator<’
  std::signal<void()> s;
                   ^
prog.cpp:12:22: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
  std::signal<void()> s;
```

Isn't `std::signal` equivalent to `boost::signal`?

Comment: This reminds me very much of [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Does your system encrypt header files? Or block [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal)?

Comment: I was thinking that `boost::signals` is included in c++11 and by similarity with other boost libs, it should have name `std::signal`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

std::signal is not even a template, you can't write `std::signal<type>;`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

They're are completely different things. boost::signal is a signal-slot framework, while std::signal (it's from C, not from C++11) is a function that sets an OS signals handler.

Comment: But why it is implemented that way?. How can I use boost.singals with C++11 compiler?

Comment: Just still use boost::signals

Answer (score 1):

`std::signal` is not related to `boost::signal`. But it is not difficult to make something like `boost::signal` without using `boost`

```
template <typename... T>
struct signal{
    typedef std::function<T...> function_type;
    typedef std::vector<function_type> container_type;

    container_type _slots;

    template <typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args){
        for(function_type f: _slots){
            f(args...);
        }
    }
    void connect(function_type slot){
        _slots.push_back(slot);
    }
};
```